# Socket.io IF and ELSE works at the same time

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
  socket.on('get-point', (data) => {
    var socketID = data.socketID;

    if(socketID === $("#socketID").text()) {
      document.getElementById("user-points").innerHTML = data.points;
      console.log('ID: ' + $("#socketID").text());
    } else {
      socket.emit('opponent-get-point');
    }
  });

      socket.on('opponent-get-point', (dataOpponent) => {
        document.getElementById("opponent-points").innerHTML = dataOpponent.points;
        console.log('oppoent gets point');
      });
```

Can someone explain me why even though `if` is correct, the `else` statement also works on my computer. Like I click the button and then the `opponent-get-point` emits also. Why this is happening ?

If opponent clicks the button then I see that he gets the point but then on his screen both players also gets the point.

Comment: It seems like this logic should be done server-side, not client-side. But that aside, one peer is saying the opponent should get the point if they're not the recipient of the point, but when the opponent receives the event, they're assigning points to their opponent, not themselves.

Comment: Why your clients emit `opponent-get-point`?

Comment: well if the button is clicked and it's not from the user (myself) then emit that socket. That means that button was clicked by another user.